# How to use a python module on inherited class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, inheritance, module

I have a base class `A` in `base.py`:

```
import module1

class A:
  def test(self):
     module1.sample("test")
```

Then in `new.py` I created a new class `B` which inherits `A` and override `test` method:

```
from base import A
class B(A):
    def test(self):
        module1.sample("test")
        print("Testing...")
```

The problem is that the `module1` is no longer available in `new.py`. Is there any options that I do not need to import `module1` again in `new.py`?

Comment: It's not clear what you need.  If `module1` is no longer available, then both classes, `A` and `B`, are no longer usable: they both depend on `module1`.

Comment: You just import the module again. That's how it is done in Python.

Comment: Hi Prune! I think I said it clearly "module1 is no longer available on the new.py"....since I created a new file named new.py

Comment: You can import the module in the A class. But then you'll have to access it through self in the B class and is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: If the function in base is very simple as given in the example you can call `super().test()` in the subclass. Or like above comments say import module1, something like `from base import A, module1` should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One **not recommended** way to achieve what you want is to use `__builtins__`. Add the following line to `base.py`.

```
__builtins__['module1'] = module1
```

Then `module1` is no longer undefined from `new.py`. It is definitely defined in `__builtins__`.

Again, it is not recommended, however, good to understand how Python works. You would better `import module1` from `new.py` as well.

```
import module1

from base import A
...
```

Comment: Hmm I don't want to take the risk with this. I guess I'll stick to the standard process. That is importing the module on top of Class B. Though thank you for this idea.

Comment: @ArielAnasco Edited to include the final choice of yours. That is the right way to do actually. But please generously consider to accept the answer because it exactly suggests **any option so that you will not import the module1 again on top of new.py** you asked.

Comment: I will @ghchoi. Thank you again for the information